# Are these two matrices similar?

Tags: matrices

$A=\begin{pmatrix} -1 &-1 \\ 0& 1 \end{pmatrix}$ and $B=\begin{pmatrix} 1 &-1 \\ 0& -1 \end{pmatrix}$.

They have same trace, determinant, charecteristic polynomial and hence char poly.

But how do I know for sure they are or not similar?

Comment: they both have the eigenvalues $-1,1$ hence those are pairwise different hence diagonalisable hence ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$A=\begin{pmatrix} -1 &-1 \\ 0& 1 \end{pmatrix}$

After I do $R_1 \gets R_1 + R_2$ and $R_1\gets
 -R_1 $ I end up with
$\begin{pmatrix} 1 &0 \\ 0& 1 \end{pmatrix}$

And for $B=\begin{pmatrix} 1 &-1 \\ 0& -1 \end{pmatrix}$. 
After I do $R_1 \gets R_1 + R_2$ and $R_2\gets
 -R_2 $ I end up with

$\begin{pmatrix} 1 &0 \\ 0& 1 \end{pmatrix}$
thus $A$ and $B$ are similar.

Comment: This is not correct. Similarity means $B=P^{-1}AP$ for some invertible matrix $P$. You haven't proved the existence of $P$. What you did prove is that $A^2=B^2=I$, but that *per se* doesn't make $A$ and $B$ similar to each other.

Comment: @user1551, I have shown that there is there are unitary matrices $U$ and $V$(product of elementary matrices) such that $U^{-1}AU=I=V^{-1}AV$ thus $VU^{-1}AUV^{-1}=B$, now let $P=UV^{-1}$.

Comment: Are you sure? Would you please write down explicitly $U$ and $V$? By the way, the product of a number of elementary matrices is not necessarily a unitary matrix.

Comment: excuse me it is  better that I say invrtible matrix

Comment: good point, Similarity is transitive.

Answer (score 1):

Take $P = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ -2 & 1 \end{pmatrix}  $. Then $P^{-1}AP=B$.